# How do you force a “Waiting to Upload” Wav format file, in iCloud Files app

Tags: iphone, icloud, music, storage, file-sharing

I’ve read some of the other posts on this issue about forcing "Waiting to Upload" files, but none of the solutions seem to work for me because I am using an iPhone 7 (transferring from iPad) and most answers seem centered on using a desktop/laptop or don't consider the limitations/capabilities of 3-D touch.

***IMPORTANT***

**1. I do not have WiFi at home.**

**2. iPhone 7 (256GB model) no longer has cellular data (got new iPhone XR 64GB) but I still use iPhone 7 for downloading songs (.WAV) I make on iPad (6th Gen, 32GB ) to VOX app and uploading to iCloud Library through Files App.**

**3. Because I don't have WiFi, once I've transferred files to Vox and Files on iPhone 7 from iPad using AirDrop, I turn on & connect to iPad's Hotspot to allow the files to upload completely (even though I can listen to the songs in entirety on both apps)**

**4. The iPad is not connected to the same iCloud account as the iPhone, but the two iCloud accounts are connected by Family Share.**

So.... The problem I'm running into is that the .WAV files (on Files App for sure, Vox doesn't provide status) still don't progress past "Waiting to Upload" status after I connect to Hotspot.

If I open the file, the songs just play but still nothing changes.

I've seen solutions like, "two-finger pressing" the file name, then selecting "save song to iCloud Library, BUT two-finger *and* one-finger long pressing the file only result as a "3-D touch", meaning the file opens in a 3-D manner but the functionality is no different than normally opening the file.

Any advice would help, I really just don't want to lose these files since they're my own songs, and it's basically necessary that I save them to the iPhone 7 since I have so little space on my other devices.

I've thought about transferring the files to my iPhone XR first and then transferring to iPhone 7 (while it's connected to iPads Hotspot) and then just deleting them from my iPad and iPhone XR, but that's kind of a lot of work, and it may not work exactly how I'd like since both iPhones are connected to the same iCloud account.